# send lengthy base64 string to webapi

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive, base64

here i'm sending post request to webapi controller with parameter of values from my angular js,
one of the parameter which contains a base64 string value,

```
$scope.upload = function(Id, formdata) {
            debugger;
            if ($scope.logoattachments[0].fileSize != '' && $scope.logoattachments[0].fileSize != null && $scope.logoattachments[0].fileSize != undefined) {
                var data = formdata //new FormData($("form")[0]);
                var urls =
                    $localStorage.apiURL +
                    "/LogoUpload?tcoid=" +
                    Id + "&documentName=" +
                    $scope.logoattachments[0].documentName +
                    "&fileName=" + $scope.logoattachments[0].fileName +
                    "&fileType=" + $scope.logoattachments[0].fileType +
                    "&fileSize=" + $scope.logoattachments[0].fileSize +
                    "&fileBaseContent=" + $scope.fileBaseContent;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: urls,
                    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    cache: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        $("p").text(data);
                        $scope.showlodebar = false;
                        $location.url("/update/" + tcoId);
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        toastr.error(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                    },
                });
            }
        };
```

**my controller code**

```
[Route("api/LogoUpload")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public string PostAction([FromUri] int id,string documentName,string fileName,string fileType,int fileSize,string fileBaseContent)
    {
        try
        {
            var userIdentity = RequestContext.Principal.Identity;
            LogoAttachment model = new LogoAttachment();
            model.documentName = documentName;
            model.fileName = fileName;
            model.fileType = fileType;
            model.fileSize = fileSize;
            model.fileBaseContent = "";
            model.createdBy = "Super Admin";
            model.createdAt = DateTime.Now;
            model.updatedBy = "Super Admin";//userIdentity.Name;
            model.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            model.isActive = true;
            model.tcoid = tcoid;
            context.LogoAttachments.Add(model);
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
            if (iUploadedCnt > 0)
            {
                return iUploadedCnt + " Files Uploaded Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Upload Failed";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

when i pass the request it shows me an http error,

anybody know the solution for **how to pass base64 string to the controller?**,please mention your answers,

thanks in advance

Comment: Base 64 string which is being passed as a parameter , is that the file content ?

Comment: yes it is @AdityaSingh

Comment: Rather than using FromUri, use FromBody to send Base64 content. Because there is a maximum length for the url, and when its get exceeded requests fails. Since Base64 are longer in length, recommend using FromBody to pass all your parameters wrapped inside a model class.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the file details as a query string parameter you can post file to the web api controller and in the controller you can grab the file from the httpcontext and parse it for further use , Please see below:-

```
var data = new formdata();
data .append('uploadedFile', document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0]);
```

and in the controller you can retreive the file using below :-

```
var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["uploadedFile"];
```

This is assuming your web api is based on .net framework , please do not set the contentType while posting the request.